# Mercurial commands equivalency

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to find out if the following Mercurial commands are equivalent (beside the additional `+` in `id -i` output if the directory is has modified files): `hg id -i` and `hg log -l1 --template "{node|short}"`. Are they or are they not?

The purpose is to potentially speed up some automation not needing to execute the `id -i` and use `{node|short}` in the `log` template instead. They seem equivalent but I'd rather if somebody else took a look as well before I proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're equivalent under certain conditions.  `log -l 1` gives you the first revision when all revisions are ordered from `tip` ("newest") to `0`.  `hg id` tells you what you currently have checked out.  So if you've not checked out tip (say you've checked out a branch org a specific revision) you'll get entirely different output:

```
ry4an@four:~/projects/mercurial-crew$ hg log -l1 --template "{node|short}\n"
7eda5bb9ec8f
ry4an@four:~/projects/mercurial-crew$ hg id -i
824f7b3545c1
```

If, however, you've checked out `tip` (and you have no modified files) then they're identical (except for log not providing a newline without `\n`):

```
ry4an@four:~/projects/mercurial-crew$ hg checkout tip
4 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
ry4an@four:~/projects/mercurial-crew$ hg id -i
7eda5bb9ec8f
ry4an@four:~/projects/mercurial-crew$ hg log -l1 --template "{node|short}\n"
7eda5bb9ec8f
```

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same, because `hg id` defaults to examining the work-tree, and:

```
$ hg merge side
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
$ hg id -i
eb51a3480d0c+62e318575165+
```

if you're in the middle of merging, the work-tree has two parents and `hg id` prints both of them.

Meanwhile, `hg log` defaults to looking at the <s>current</s> (oops, thanks to [Ry4an Brase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043917/1256452)) *tip commit* (rather than the work-tree); `{node | short}` prints its ID:

```
$ hg log -l1 --template '{node|short}'
eb51a3480d0c
```

On the other hand, if you're *not* in the middle of a merge, the work-tree has only one parent.  You can also specify the revision `.`, which is the current commit ... so *in that case*, they are effectively the same.